# How to get last signals?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I have an indicator that generates signals based on several criteria and sometimes bars achieve the criterion and other ones did not achieve. How can I make not achieve criterion bars have the previously achieved criterion bar signal?

Answer (score 0):

use your signal with index [1],
for example if signal name(variable) is your_signal use:

```
your_signal[1]
```